# Bloomberg BDS function

Tags: bloomberg

I'm using the following code to capture the cash flows of specific ISIN's:

```
Cells(i + 1, j + 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=BDS(CONCATENATE("""",R[-1]C[-1],"" "",""ISIN"",""""), ""DES_CASH_FLOW"",""SETTLE_DT"",R[-1]C[1])"
```

The problem is that when I run it for a specif date, for example 10/17/2014, if there is a coupon close to that date, for example, 10/20/2014, this coupon is not captured because the dates are close.

Is there a way to work on that function so I can capture all coupons doesn't matter the date?

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? i.e. your example makes references to excel cells, which we don't have... if you inline all the references, what is the actual `=BDS(...)` call that you are making?